# How do you handle references to variables in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a function that I want to operate on one of a number of different global variables (in this case global-mark-list, a buffers mark-list or an arbitrary list of marks). As the function is called from a tabulated-menu function I need to stash the reference in a buffer local variable for later access.

What's the best way to handle this is elisp? Looking through the manual there is mention of defvaralias and indirect-variable but this seems more set up for permanent global aliasing rather than a temporary reference. Am I missing some subtly of lisp that means this should be very easy?

Comment: It looks like I was over-thinking this one and could just reference the list simply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the variable's name as a symbol and use `symbol-value` or `eval`.

A lot of dynamic languages have `eval`.

Comment: If you can use `symbol-value` instead of `eval`, please do not use `eval`.  Kind of like, if you can do it fine with a spoon, don't do it a bulldozer.

Comment: What do I do when I want to change the real value that my variable points to?

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs's trunk (to become 24.4) you can also use `gv-ref` and `gv-deref`, which work similarly to C's `&` and `*` respectively.

Comment: What's the rationale for introducing these new methods in 24.4? Especially if there are already ways of achieving this?

Comment: @stsquad These functions work with “generalized variables” to access and manipulate arbitrary storage places, not only variable cells of symbols.  Essentially these functions generalize `setf` and related functions to support arbitrary types, including but not limited to CL structures or EIEIO objects.

Comment: There are several motivations for adding `gv-(de)ref`: one reason is that they work not just with variables but with any *generalized variable* (aka *lvalue*, or settable field), another is that `set` and `symbol-value` only work on dynamically-scoped variables but not on lexically-scoped variables.